# hom many terms will consist only one $x$ and others $y$'s?

Tags: combinatorics

suppose I expand the product $(x_1+y_1)\dots(x_{20}+y_{20})$, I just want to know hommany terms will consist only one $x$ and others $y$'s?

Comment: I tried for $(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)$ and got $2$ as an answer

Comment: Can you try for $(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)(x_3+y_3)$ and maybe form a hypothesis?

Comment: I have upvoted your question since you have shown what you tried in comments, but it would be better if you added that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** there is one term with $x_1$ and $y_2y_3y_4\dots y_{20}$.

**Another Hint:** there is one term with $x_2$ and $y_1y_3y_4\dots y_{20}$.